# Oracle 12c: ORDER BY sortings work, except the fallback mechanic

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by, oracle12c

I have a little problem with an Oracle 12c database and data sorting.

This is my table:

```
ID    | DATE       | INVOICENO | SUBJECT
10000 | 01.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub1
10001 | 01.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub2
10002 | 03.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub3
10003 | 05.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub4
[...]
```

This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FOO_ORDERS.INVOICENO, 
FOO_ORDERS.SUBJECT, 
FOO_ORDERS.DATE, 
FOO_ORDERS.ID

FROM FOO_ORDERS

WHERE FOO_ORDERS.ID >= 10000 AND FOO_ORDERS.ID <= 10500

ORDER BY FOO_ORDERS.INVOICENO
```

So i execute this sql statement in two different Oracle installations.

Result server1:

```
ID    | DATE       | INVOICENO | SUBJECT
10000 | 01.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub1
10001 | 01.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub2
10002 | 03.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub3
10003 | 05.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub4
[...]
```

You see that ORDER BY sorts the INVOICENO (but every row is NULL) and after that it sorts by ID ASC. That is the correct and the needed result.

Result server2:

```
ID    | DATE       | INVOICENO | SUBJECT
10002 | 03.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub3    
10001 | 01.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub2
10003 | 05.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub4
10000 | 01.08.2019 | NULL      | Sub1
[...]
```

You see that ORDER BY sorts different to server1. It's totally random and so the result is wrong.

I don't know why this two oracle databases acts differently.

How sorts oracle if the first and only column hin the ORDER BY has in all columns the same value (in this case NULL)?

I need your help to "repair" server2.

Comment: In the absence of an effective `order by`, the ordering will depend on how the data is physically stored, and the execution plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (well, technically multi-sets).  There is no "default" ordering unless a column specifies that ordering.

This has an impact when you use `ORDER BY`, both for a query and in analytic functions.  Ordering is *unstable*.  That means that when multiple rows have the same key values, then the ordering is not determined.

The ordering of a result set can change when running the same query twice on the same system.  Or on a different system with the same data.

If you want a stable sort, include a unique key at the end of the `order by` as a default when the other key values are the same.  In this case, `id` would appear to be an appropriate column:

```
order by invoice_id, id
```

Comment: Wise words. Many of us learned this when we relied on `GROUP BY` to provide sorted results in older versions of Oracle. Then one day (11g?) Oracle changed the default algorithm for doing `GROUP BY` so we didn't get that automatic sort. The moral of the story: if you expect columns to be sorted by A,B,C, and D then put an explicit order-by saying exactly that, plus a tiebreaker unique key at the end to ensure stable sorting.

Comment: I run this query multiple times (x20) on both servers. Always the same result. This is strange...

Comment: Additional info:
Server1 always sort by ID if there doesn't exists a ORDER BY statement or the columns in ORDER BY has the same values.

There must be a parameter or something like that, which activate a default sorting via primary column.

Comment: @Athris . . . The point is that you cannot depend on the results unless the `ORDER BY` is stable.  It might be consistent on one version (particularly if the query is processed using only one thread).  But you should not *depend* on that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an implicit order by ins SQL   ..so when you need  add the explict order by  for ID

```
SELECT DISTINCT FOO_ORDERS.INVOICENO, 
FOO_ORDERS.SUBJECT, 
FOO_ORDERS.DATE, 
FOO_ORDERS.ID
FROM FOO_ORDERS
WHERE FOO_ORDERS.ID >= 10000 AND FOO_ORDERS.ID <= 10500
ORDER BY FOO_ORDERS.INVOICENO, FOO_ORDERS.ID
```